# Why does JS stop execution of the main thread when there is a while loop in an async function of promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop

Why does JS stop executing the rest of the code after executing an async function with a while loop in it? And also how do I fix it?

I`m doing a more complex thing but I decided that this code is good enough for the question.

```
async function foo(){
    while(true){}
}
foo();
console.log("stuff");
```

I expected it to console log 'stuff', but instead the whole program just stopped executing.

Comment: `while(true){}` is infinite loop, and thread hangs, not async causing the problem

Comment: The `async` keyword does not change the way non-asynchronous code works.

Comment: but is there a way to wait in an async function until something happens whitout stopping the rest of the code?

Comment: Sure, `await`... ?

Comment: I mean for example wait for an event to happen.

Comment: @СпасимирПавлов Yes, you make a promise for the event happening and `await` that.

Comment: Can you show a quick example.

Comment: A quick google reveals thousands of tutorials, each with a few examples.

Comment: will this work? ```let p = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {something.on("foo",() => {return resolve("good")})});```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does JS stop execution of the main thread when there is a while loop ...

It does not stop execution. It executes the while loop *infinitively*.

> ... in an async function?

That doesn't matter. As you pointed out, JS is single threaded, so there is no concurrency.

> how do I fix it?

Don't create infinite loops.